# How to improve and make more robust add class and remove class on menu items?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to improve my sort of code? I'm trying to add / remove classes of `active` or `check` in a menu item. My menus are like steps with a `prev` and `next` button.

My only goal here is to reduce and improve the jQuery code.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="test-sidebar">

    <ul class="menus list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#" data-target="test_1"><span>Test 1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-target="test_2"></i><span>Test 2</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-target="test_3"><span>Test 3</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-target="test_4"><span>Test 4</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-target="test_5"><span>Test 5</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-target="test_6"><span>Test 6</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-target="test_7"><span>Test 7</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<button data-target="test_2" class="prev-page-btn w-100">Back</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // load the function
    prevPageButtons();
  });

// function for Previous buttons
function prevPageButtons() {
    // setting target from data attributes
    var target, container;
  
    $("body").on("click", ".prev-page-btn", function (e) {
      target = $(this).attr('data-target'),
        container = $('#get_content');
  
      container.load(target + '.php');
  
      if (target == "test_1") {
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:first-child").removeClass('check').addClass('active');
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(2)").removeClass('active');
      }
  
      if (target == "test_2") {
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(2)").removeClass('check').addClass('active');
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(3)").removeClass('active');
      }
  
      if (target == "test_3") {
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(3)").removeClass('check').addClass('active');
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(4)").removeClass('active');
      }
  
      if (target == "test_4") {
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(4)").removeClass('check').addClass('active');
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(5)").removeClass('active');
      }
  
      if (target == "test_5") {
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(5)").removeClass('check').addClass('active');
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(6)").removeClass('active');
      }
  
      if (target == "test_6") {
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(6)").removeClass('check').addClass('active');
        $(".test-sidebar ul li:nth-child(7)").removeClass('active');
      }
  
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to reduce the `nth-childs` / by not using nth-childs of my menu items in my `jQuery`. Is there anyway to achieve this by not using `nth-childs` for removing and adding classes. I'm thinking of using `prevAll()` function or any sorts, but how do I achieve it?

Just want to focus on improving the `jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `data-target`, you can get to the element to add `active` to, then use [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next sibling.

It would also be good to use a different data attribute - don't use the same one for the button and the `<a>`s. Maybe call the `<a>`s the `data-name` instead, eg

```
<a href="#" data-name="test_1"><span>Test 1</span></a>
```

Then, replace all of the

```
if (target == "test_1") {
```

with only:

```
$("body").on("click", ".prev-page-btn", function(e) {
  const target = $(this).attr('data-target');
  const container = $('#get_content');
  const li = $(`[data-name="${target}"]`).parent();
  li.removeClass('check').addClass('active');
  li.next().removeClass('check');
});
```

Live demo:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".prev-page-btn", function(e) {
  const target = $(this).attr('data-target');
  const container = $('#get_content');
  const li = $(`[data-name="${target}"]`).parent();
  li.removeClass('check').addClass('active');
  li.next().removeClass('check');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.check {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="test-sidebar">

  <ul class="menus list-unstyled components">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-name="test_1"><span>Test 1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="check">
      <a href="#" data-name="test_2"></i><span>Test 2</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="check">
      <a href="#" data-name="test_3"><span>Test 3</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-name="test_4"><span>Test 4</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-name="test_5"><span>Test 5</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-name="test_6"><span>Test 6</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-name="test_7"><span>Test 7</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<button data-target="test_2" class="prev-page-btn w-100">Back</button>
```

Depending on how the `<button>`s are arranged, you might be able to get rid of the data attributes altogether and instead use the index of the button clicked to navigate to the same indexed `<li>`.

Comment: I have tried it , it seems to be not working.

Comment: Edited a live snippet into the question